# Using where condition for CASE statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL statement of the below format:

```
SELECT 
    p.env, p.name, i.sys_name, i.hostname,
    CASE
       WHEN (COUNT(DISTINCT p.env) OVER (PARTITION BY i.sys_name) +
             COUNT(DISTINCT i.sys_name) OVER (PARTITION BY i.sys_name)) = 2
          THEN 'no issues'
          ELSE 'has issues'
    END AS result
FROM 
    instances i 
JOIN 
    properties p ON i.target_name = p.target_name
```

How can I add a where condition such that I can get only the rows with result as 'has issues'.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Something is definitely wrong with your code (meaning: whatever problem it is supposed to solve, this code is very likely an incorrect solution). You have a count DISTINCT of i.sys_name after you partition by i.sys_name. That makes no sense; in each individual partition, the count DISTINCT will be exactly 1. (Except when i.sys_name is NULL in which case the count is zero.) So... perhaps we can help you better if you tell us what you are trying to do, rather than how you think it should be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One obvious solution is a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT p.env, p.name, i.sys_name, i.hostname,
             (CASE WHEN (COUNT(DISTINCT p.env) OVER (PARTITION BY i.sys_name) +
                         COUNT(DISTINCT i.sys_name) OVER (PARTITION BY i.sys_name)
                        ) = 2
                  THEN 'no issues' ELSE 'has issues'
               END) AS result
      FROM instances i JOIN
           properties p
           ON i.target_name = p.target_name
     ) ip
WHERE result = 'has issues';
```